# passing text input into php script

Tags: php, html, forms

I have made a simple website for my nieces and nephews to send a letter to santa. I have a php mail script that I use as a contact form regularly and want to modify it for this project by somehow taking the parents email address, which will be input in a text input, and pass it to the send to email in my script. I am not very experienced with PHP, I have only ever created this PHP mail script from code I found online. I'm guessing somehow I can set the name of the text input to something that I can call in my script somehow? Any help is much appreciated! I suppose a simpler form of the question would be, how do I pass a string that is input into an html text input to a variable in a PHP script?

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Parent's Email" maxlength="50" minlength="10">
```

That is what I have for my text input. My PHP script is a seperate file and is here https://pastebin.com/dQ4tFyyL

```
$email_to = "This is where I'd like the email to be passed";
```

I hope that clears up my question. Sorry this is my first time using this site, I can generally find answers on Google but am having a heck of a time with this one.

Comment: A good first step would be to post what you have and are working on.  Then ask questions about specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Can you post the code of the contact us form?

Comment: Code for my PHP script is here https://pastebin.com/dQ4tFyyL

Comment: So I'd just like the string that the user enters into the "parents email" text input box passed to the PHP script into the variable that I have marked as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$email_to = $_POST['email'];
```

Make sure your form use `method="post"`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Boris, this worked perfectly! My nieces and nephews and anyone else who finds the site will be thrilled! Happy Holidays to you sir.

Comment: If anyone would like to use the final product it is live at dearsanta.fun

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you need to POST your form data into .php script, i think you can use ajax like this,

```js
$('form').submit(function(event) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize()
      }).done(function (data) {
           //if success 
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           //if error   
      });
});
```

Then you can use post data in .php script like this,

```
$email_to = $POST['email'];
```